# Render Partial VIew After Submit in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdown, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have two Dropdown and after selecting values from these dropdowns, I want to display report as a partial View.

Answer (score 0):

Your describing an issue that will be easily solved with client side code. You'll have to use javascript onclick function(s) for rendering all information that will change based on your selected values. You could still make use of your partial view, you'll just have to change the relevant values. If you have any information that needs to be retrieved from a database, you can make use of JS post requests.

If you can't use javascript, you'll have to reload the page with the selected values passed back to your controller function that obtains your information.